# How to send transaction with the same nonce?

Tags: web3.py, python

How to resend transaction with the same nonce using python web3?

I'm getting error: known transaction once trying to initiate the transaction with the same nonce.

Comment: Why do you want to send with the same nonce anyway?

Comment: @always_beta I want to replace tx

Comment: nonce should increase no matter whether the transaction succeed or failed, if you haven't send the transaction, then just re-compose it and send, if you already sent the transaction, and it ended up with failure, you have to increase the nonce.

Comment: @Rigg you're only problem is that you need to increase the gas price (by at least 10%). The error is telling you that the nodes already have your tx in the mempool, so you don't need to send another identical one

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same nonce twice, as per the definition of nonce:

> In cryptography, a value that can only be used once. There are two types of nonce used in Ethereum- an account nonce is a transaction counter in each account, which is used to prevent replay attacks; a proof-of-work nonce is the random value in a block that was used to satisfy the proof-of-work.

From [ethereum.org](https://ethereum.org/en/glossary/#nonce)